# Button being triggered twice and element not being rendered anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have this weather page that every time I click the button it changes from Celcius to Fahrenheit or vice-versa.

What is happening is that once I click the first time, it works fine, but then if I click it again or more times, my console log shows that it executes it twice and does not render the element anymore (#link).

```
            $("#data").on('click', '#link', function () {
            var html2 = "";
            html2 += '<button class="temp" id="link">'
            if (flag == 0){
                console.log("c to f");
                html2 += "<h1>" + celciusToFahrenheit(Math.round(json.main.temp)) + " °F</h1>";
                flag = 1;
            } else if (flag == 1){
                console.log("f to c");
                html2 += "<h1>" + Math.round(json.main.temp) + " °C</h1>";
                flag = 0;
            }
            html2 += "</button>"
            $("#link").html(html2);
        });
```

I am including the entire file bellow:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getCurrentLocation(callback) {
        if (!navigator.geolocation) return;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            url = ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&units=metric&appid=b464bb8dd84e7e7d36103593a472ae9a');
            callback(url);
        });
    }

    function celciusToFahrenheit(celcius) {
        var fahrenheit = celcius * (9 / 5) + 32;
        return fahrenheit;
    }

    getCurrentLocation(function(currLocMap) {
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            var html = "";
            var flag = 0;

            html += '<button class="temp" id="link">'
            html += "<h1>" + Math.round(json.main.temp) + " °C </h1>";
            html += "</button>"

            html += "<h1>" + json.name + "</h1>";
            html += "<h3>" + json.weather[0].main + "</h3>";
            html += "<h3>" + json.weather[0].description + "</h3>";

   $("#data").on('click', '#link', function () {
    var html2 = "";
    html2 += '<button class="temp" id="link">'
    if (flag == 0){
     console.log("c to f");
     html2 += "<h1>" + celciusToFahrenheit(Math.round(json.main.temp)) + " °F</h1>";
     flag = 1;
     console.log(flag);
    } else if (flag == 1){
     console.log("f to c");
     html2 += "<h1>" + Math.round(json.main.temp) + " °C</h1>";
     flag = 0;
     console.log(flag);
    }
    html2 += "</button>"
    $("#link").html(html2);
   });

            console.log(json);
            console.log(json.name);
            console.log(json.main.temp);
            console.log(json.weather[0].main);
            console.log(json.weather[0].description);
            console.log(json.weather[0].icon);

            $("#data").html(html);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
button#link { background:none;border:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Weather</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="data">
        <h4>You are here:</h4>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include your html code

Comment: That's because you are rendering the same element inside itself? Can you show us the HTML code as well to get better clarity? Also, one page cannot have 2 elements with same ID as per standard #JustAnFYI

Comment: The html is pretty empty. I just replace a div #data with actually what I get from a weather API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're recreating the button inside the click event handler. You should change the content of the h1 tag in your handler instead of recreating the entire button, something like so:

```
 $("h1",$(this)).html("new content");
```

Comment: thanks that totally worked! Do you know how to explain why creating a new button makes it not working anymore? If I actually need to create other buttons, how do I make them work then?